# Do mock files get bundled in the build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocking, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app`.

To test React components I'm using Jest and with that mock files.

I place the test file and the adhering mock file next to the component, like this file structure:

```
components
- account
-- Account.js
-- Account.test.js
-- __mocks.js
- another-feature
....
```

When I run `yarn build`, will the mock files be bundled as well?

Comment: no, until you explicitly `import '__mocks.js'` in your component's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yarn(or npm) relies on entry point you specify. Then webpack goes to every single `import` starting from entry point(s). Then tree-shaking happens. And finally everything gathered goes to bundle.

Jest works in different way: it searches by filename pattern for tests, mocks and snapshots. Then every single test file becomes entry point for webpack while running.

So these are 2 independent flows and special files/directories(like `__mocks__`) or files that are required by test files only(like `__mocks.js` in your case) will not go to bundle.